# Adzerk goes berserk

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertising

I was on StackOverflow and clicked on this ad, and got a 404:

[image]

http://engine.adzerk.net/redirect/0/2663/2640/8277/276fbc36a00b46968bc6899360160db1/45/1178/634306270792703639?keywords=c#,windows,transactions,editor,binaryfiles,x-user-highrep,x-user-registered,x-200plus-rep&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapple.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F6387%2Fhow-to-setup-a-default-program-opening-an-unknown-file-extension

None of the Adzerk redirects appear to be working.

Comment: What browser, and do you have javascript running?  Part of the URL is missing, which is why it doesn't work.

Comment: IE8 with Javascript enabled.  I see the additional part of the Url that you're talking about, so I pasted in a new example, still no joy.  Oddly enough, Firefox works.

Comment: IE8 appears to be truncating the URL when it attempts to redirect.

Comment: @David: See my edit and subsequent comments.

Comment: it's because the "c#" isn't escaped in the list of keywords -- we'll get that fixed ASAP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be fixed now.  The ad code wasn't escaping the "#" in "c#" in the URL.